# Local Reference table overflow but using DeleteLocalRef

Tags: android, jnienv

I am forking the breadwallet and get a `LocalReferenceTableOverflow`.
It is in the following code

```
static void saveBlocks(void *info, BRMerkleBlock *blocks[], size_t count){
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Message from C: ", "saveBlocks");
if (!_peerManager){
    return;
}

JNIEnv *env = getEnv();
jmethodID mid;

if (!env) return;

if (count != 1) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Message from C: ", "deleting %zu blocks", count);
    mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, _peerManagerClass, "deleteBlocks", "()V");
    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, _peerManagerClass, mid);
}

//call java methods

//Find the class and populate the array of objects of this class
jobjectArray blockObjectArray = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, (jsize) count, _blockClass, 0);

for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (!_peerManager) return;

    uint8_t buf[BRMerkleBlockSerialize(blocks[i], NULL, 0)];
    size_t len = BRMerkleBlockSerialize(blocks[i], buf, sizeof(buf));
    jbyteArray result = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, (jsize) len);
    jobject blockObject;

    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, result, 0, (jsize) len, (jbyte *) buf);
    mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, _blockClass, "<init>", "([BI)V");

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "huhu", "hier bin ich gleich");
    blockObject = (*env)->NewObject(env, _blockClass, mid, result, blocks[i]->height); // this line
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "huhu", "hier bin ich");

    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, blockObjectArray, i, blockObject);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, result);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, blockObject);
}

mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, _peerManagerClass, "saveBlocks",
                                "([Lcom/breadwallet/presenter/entities/BlockEntity;)V");
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, _peerManagerClass, mid, blockObjectArray);
}
```

LogCat:

```
05-13 01:52:11.644 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet D/com.breadwallet.wallet.BRPeerManager: saveBlocks: 1
05-13 01:52:11.644 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet D/Message from C:: saveBlocks
05-13 01:52:11.644 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet D/Message from C:: getEnv peerManager
05-13 01:52:11.644 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet D/huhu: hier bin ich gleich
05-13 01:52:11.646 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
05-13 01:52:11.646 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] local reference table dump:
05-13 01:52:11.646 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]   Last 10 entries (of 512):
05-13 01:52:11.646 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       511: 0x12e9c880 byte[] (80 elements)
05-13 01:52:11.646 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       510: 0x12c51700 com.breadwallet.presenter.entities.BlockEntity[] (1 elements)
05-13 01:52:11.646 28316-28449/com.eMarkwallet A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       509: 0x12c51140 com.breadwallet.presenter.entities.BlockEntity[] (1 elements)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The blockentity is linked 511 times.